# diffrence between ls -l *.<sometthing> | wc -l and ls -l | grep <something> | wc -l

Tags: grep, zsh, ls, wc

I have a folder with a huge file list that I want to count. I was doing `ls -l *.json | wc -l` and it was working fine, till the list apparently gone huge enough that this command didn't work any more.

I tried that later one `ls -l | grep .json | wc -l` and it worked like a charm.

So I want to know what is the difference between both? I think it's because  the later does not `ls` all the file at once but rather streams the files continuously in the `grep` and then to `wc`? Is it so, or it works differently?

Comment: Sounds like your original command was `ls -l *.json | wc -l` rather than `ls -l | wc -l`. The latter is fine because it doesn't rely on the shel to expand the file list. The former might fail if the expanded list of files is too long.

Comment: Would probably help to include detail in your question of any the errors you received.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson yes u r right. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of non-hidden files that have a `.json` extensions in the current directory, you'd do:

```
(){echo $#} *.json(NoN)
```

(`N` for `nullglob`, `oN` to disable sorting which we don't need here).

`ls -l | grep .json | wc -l` is wrong for a number of reasons:

- `.` is a regexp operator that match any single character. If you wanted to search for the `.json` string that would be `grep -F .json` or `grep '\.json'` or `grep '[.]json'`.
- That `Xjson` is looked for on each line. With `ls -l`, you're printing the file name, the user name, the group name, the target of symlinks all of which could contain `Xjson`.
- also file names may contain any byte value except 0 and that of `/` (link targets can contain `/`); that includes newline. So if you have a file called `xjson\nyjson` that is a symlink to `ajson\nbjson`, without `-q`, `ls -l` for that file will print 3 lines all of which will contain `Xjson`. You may also get surprises if some file names contain sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters in the current locale.
- `grep | wc -l` can generally be replaced with `grep -c`.

`ls -l *.json | wc -l` is even worse. Beside the *arg list too long potential problem* already noted by @L.ScottJohnson, there's also:

- if there's no non-hidden `.json` file, you'll get `0` but also an error from `zsh` as the `*.json` glob fails to match.
- For each of the arguments that are of type *directory*, `ls -l` lists their content, so if you have a `dir.json` directory, all the lines resulting from its listing will be counted. Generally, you want to use a `-d` when passing a glob expansion to `ls`.
- If any of the `.json` filename starts with `-`, that will be taken as an option by `ls` (especially the GNU or busybox implementations of `ls` which accept options even after non-option arguments).
- like above, you'll have problems if the filename or symlink target contains newlines.

You could fix most of those with something like:

```
LC_ALL=C ls -qd -- *.json | wc -l
```

But in there, all the actual job is done by the shell. The shell is the one which expands `*.json` to the list of matching files and passes it to `ls`. `ls` is only used there to print each on a separate line to feed to `wc` so it can count them. `ls` also does a lot of unnecessary work like doing a `stat()` system call on each to check it's there (with `-l`, it does a `lstat()` and a few uid/gid to user/group name resolutions, and `readlink()`s for symlinks), and sorts the list again (the shell already sorts the `*.json` expansion).

The shell is well able to count that expansion by itself.

With `(){echo $#} *.json(NoN)`, we use an anonymous function, you could also use a temporary array: `files=(*.json(NoN)); echo $#files`.

Also note that it only needs to *read* the contents of the current directory to build that list, it doesn't need to try and look-up each file individually like `ls` does.

Note that that syntax is specific to `zsh`. The equivalent in a POSIX `sh` would be something like:

```
set -- [*].json *.json
case $1$2 in
  ('[*].json*.json') shift 2;;
  (*) shift;;
esac
echo "$#"
```

(and the list of files is in `"$@"` (sorted)).

Answer (score 1):

Your original command might fail if the expanded list of files is too long, since it relies on the shell to expand the list of files.

```
ls -l | grep .json | wc -l
```

Is OK because the command line is short (no expansion) and the grep does the filtering line by line instead.

Note that the dot matches any character, not just a dot. Use -F to indicate fixed strings:

```
ls -l | grep -F .json | wc -l
```

so you don't accidentally match the file `xjson` or something similarly silly.

There are still caveats for this command as well, and other (more robust) ways to achieve your desired goal, but those issues aside, this is the difference between the two commands: filtering by filename globbing (i.e., shell expansion) vs. pipe-to-grep

Comment: still weird for me why expansion on the fly doesn't work while grep does. sounds to me the exact same operation, as grep checks for a specific string and *.json checks also for a specific string.

Comment: The difference is that in one, the complete list of .json files is being expanded by the shell and fed on the command line as arguments to ls. In the other, the entire (long listing) list of files is being piped from the output of ls to the input of grep. Pipes have no size restriction, the command line does.